# udev rule to auto-backup USB drive not running full script

Tags: bash, shell, usb-drive, udev

I have a project in Linux to trigger scripts to run actions on a newly inserted USB drive. (Udev hook)

One script I want to run is a backup that copies the USB drive contents using a C program. The current script (triggered by udev rule):

```
#!/bin/bash
sleep 5

backuplocation=$(echo /home/student/backuplocation)
mountlocation=$(echo /home/student/mountlocation)

sudo mkdir -p /home/student/backuplocation
sudo mkdir -p /home/student/mountlocation
sudo mount /dev/sdb1 /home/student/mountlocation

sleep 5  
sudo ./backup /home/student/mountlocation /home/student/backuplocation
sleep 10
sudo umount /home/student/mountlocation
```

The udev rule:

```
SUBSYSTEM=="block", ACTION=="add", ATTRS{idVendor}=="058f", RUN+="/usr/local/bin/trigger.sh"
```

When running the script line-by-line, the backup works. But when inserting the USB drive, it only creates the directories with mkdir and does not run the "./backup" executable to copy contents.

Second problem, how can I automate this process fully without hardcoding the USB mount location? (currently uses default of /dev/sdb1). I need the location of the newly added USB without hardcoding it.

If i execute it line by line it works, but if i just connect the USB it just creates the 2 folders "backuplocation" and "mountlocation", without having something in them (empty).

Comment: Please take a look at [How do I format my posts using Markdown or HTML?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting).

Comment: To get some useful hints paste your script at http://www.shellcheck.net/.

Comment: It's my (unclear, hazy) understanding that the `{idVendor}=="058f` information is not unique to each USB drive. If you had multiple drives of the same model/brand/manufacturer, they would all respond with `058f`. That seems like that would be a problem for your use-case, but please comment. Good luck.

Comment: You should read [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/752032/203203) to learn why this is not a good idea to mount within udev (especially the part about sandboxing). In addition to that, your script has many issues: useless calls to `sudo`, useless command substitution (`echo`) to define variables, assumption about current working directory, long sleeps (in udev, really?)

Comment: The lack of error checking in the script is asking for trouble. Use `set -e`. Some people will tell you not to, citing one of the lists of “pitfalls“. You see, `set -e` is like seatbelts. Seatbelts cause cuts and bruises. Yet they are still _way_ better used than unused. (How does the script check if `mount` succeeds? Why is it not read-only? What if a `mkdir` command fails? What if `umount` interferes with something?) Last but not least, avoid unconditional `sleep`s for bogus time periods. Wait passively, ideally. If you have to busy-wait, busy-wait. But do wait for real, don’t just `sleep`.